# The numbered list button in the editor does not behave as expected

Tags: feature-request, behavior, editor

This is what I want to do, and is a very common pattern in just about any editor that lets you create numbered lists.

I want to create a list by typing each step on a new line.

step one
step two
step three

I then want to highlight these lines and create a numbered list where each new line is assigned a number.  If I highlight all three lines in the editor and click the numbered list button in the toolbar, this is what I get:

1. step one   step two   step three

Is this in any way expected behavior?  Would *anybody* expect that to happen?  Does *anybody* want this to be the normal behavior?  I don't think so.

Comment: I still think this should be implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170349/the-editor-should-be-able-to-convert-multi-line-blocks-to-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so hard:

1. Step one
2. Step two.  Note that it will even wrap lines correctly, as this boring (but long) line of text will demonstrate for you.
3. Step three

Here's what the text looks like (encased in a pre block):

```
1. Step one
1. Step two  Note that it will even wrap lines correctly, as this boring (but long) line of text will demonstrate for you .
1. Step three
```

Markdown handles this for you.  Notice that it doesn't care what number I actually typed, but will put an ordered number in automatically.

But I take your point about the button on the toolbar being broken.

Comment: You can't apply a list to X number of lines.  That's the problem I'm having.  Yes, I can create a numbered list by clicking the button on every friggen line, but it doesn't behave as expected when doing multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find it difficult to continue the numbering pattern after a block of code or quote. A handful of times I've had to throw out the autonumbers from Markdown and explicitly number my points manually.

This isn't meant to be a nitpick, and perhaps that functionality has been patched or enhanced.

Comment: But can you get the same formatting for the pre and post numbers?