# The editor should be able to convert multi-line blocks to lists

Tags: feature-request, bug, editor, list

Let's say I write up a bunch of rows and decide I want to make it a list:

```
Item 1
Another Item
Something Else
```

When I mark each line and click the "List" button (doesn't matter which one), the Editor takes all three rows and makes one list item out of them, ignoring the line-breaks.

The output will simply be:

```
- Item 1 Another Item Something Else
```

It would be far more useful and less buggy if it would instead create **one list item *for each line***:

```
- Item 1
- Another Item
- Something Else
```

Comment: Please! Especially with all the new users who post lists in code blocks or quotes. This would make editing so much easier!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: The idea is that the conversion from `Item` to `- Item` is applied when the button is pressed, instead of gluing the lines together.

Comment: @minitech it appears I misread that. Oops

Comment: +1 so much! I've always been so frustrated with the way this works, but never thought to make a meta post about it. The list button is completely broken (same problem with numbered lists too). I always end up typing in the markup directly for lists.

Comment: If you meant to bump the question with that edit, please make your edits substantial. Otherwise just offer a bounty.

Comment: @Bart didn't mean to bump. But bounty sounds good.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want your list to all be on one line.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this [userscript for Chrome](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2833/903) (should be easy to make it work on Firefox):

[image]

Comment: Any Safari support?

Comment: @Peanut no idea