# How to itemize?

Tags: support, list

I sometime wants to copy paste a list to a StackExchange question or answer:

```
Connect to the remote computer with IP address and password.
Once connected, press function key F8 and click "Options"
Click "Load / Save"
Click "Save As"
Choose a name which suits you and click "Save"
At the VNC Viewer : Warning about storing the password, click "Yes".
```

and I need to add the `-` at the beginning of each item of the list:

```
- Connect to the remote computer with IP address and password.
- Once connected, press function key F8 and click "Options"
- Click "Load / Save"
- Click "Save As"
- Choose a name which suits you and click "Save"
- At the VNC Viewer : Warning about storing the password, click "Yes".
```

Is there any way (button/shortcut/etc.) to do this at once?

Comment: You can use a text editor to do this "quickly", otherwise I don't think it's a big hassle...: `home + ( hyphen + down arrow + left arrow) * N`... you should be able to do what you have here in a second or two...

Comment: Not possible at the moment. [Feature request already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170349/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks!