# Adding auto numbering for numbered list

Tags: feature-request, bug, markdown, editor, list

Problem 1:

1. Open a form for asking a question
2. Write several paragraphs of text
3. Select all of them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
4. Expected result: several list items; actual result: only one numbered line

Problem 2:

1. Write a line of text
2. Select line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
3. Place cursor at the end of line
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Expected result: new *numbered* line created; actual result: just new line

Note that if new numbered line is not needed user should press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second time and numbering is removed.

#### Bug or feature

I do not know should this be considered as a bug or feature request, but creating numbered lists is annoying. I have to press Enter, space, one keyboard, dot and space again just to add new line.

Consider also Atlassian engine for editing forms; it automatically adds numbers when you press Enter and removes it when you press it again. Also it supports making several paragraphs numbered. The Google Docs do not allow you to write raw text markup, but numbering works the same way.

Comment: with Problem 2 you can press shift + enter at the end of a list item and the next list item will be created for you with the cursor after the space in-front of the `.` but problem 1 yeh that's weird even when you double hit enter it doesn't make each text line separate list items

Comment: First problem is a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170349/the-editor-should-be-able-to-convert-multi-line-blocks-to-lists, but I don't think second one has been reported yet.